# How are existence and location expressed in English according to these Russian examples?

Tags: значения

What's the difference between the following patterns and how are they rendered in English?

1. Яблоки в холодильнике?
2. В холодильнике яблоки?
3. Есть яблоки в холодильнике?
4. Яблоки в холодильнике есть?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, there is some difference:

1. Яблоки в холодильнике? Are the apples in the fridge? (or maybe somewhere else, on the table, in the basket)?
   You're asking about the place. The logical stress is on the last word.
2. В холодильнике яблоки? Are there *apples* in the fridge? (not any other fruits like peaches or plums)
   The stress is on the last word. You're asking about the fruit because you're not sure.
3. Есть яблоки в холодильнике? — Are there any apples in the fridge?
   Just a general question about the availability of apples in the fridge.
4. Яблоки в холодильнике есть? — In English, it's exactly the same question: *Are* there any apples in the fridge?
   It's about their availability as well, but the last word is stressed and sounds more emphatic.

Comment: What a great answer; something for English learners *and* Russian learners 

Comment: @CocoPop Can the fourh sentense have a tinge of a little expostulation, admonition, rebuke? Something like this: "I wish it would finally go down so as for me to find those darn apples in this fridge at last, somehow, whenever!"

Comment: @Eugene Given the right intonation, almost *anything* can be a rebuke. But yes, if you stress "are" at the beginning of the question, it can be a rebuke of sorts: *Are* there any apples in the refrigerator? (especially if you doubt there are or if other times, you've looked for apples there and they've been gone).

Comment: @CocoPop Thank you! (by the way, is my sentense "I wish it would finally go down so as for me to find those apples in this fridge" correct? I've had a doubt as to the "...so as for me to find..." part. Maybe it should have been brought in like: "...so as for my finding..."?)

Comment: @Eugene To be honest, it didn't make a lot of sense, but I understood the context  I think you meant something like: Just this once, I'd love to go downstairs and actually find some damn apples in the refrigerator for a change!

Comment: @CocoPop I meant: "I wish it would so happen one day that I will find some apples in this fridge" but I wanted to use "..so as...". How shall it correctly sound if put using "...so as..., for all that? Thank you.

Comment: @Eugene The problem is that *so as to* means для того чтобы... so I don't know how to work it into what you're trying to say.

Comment: @CocoPop So do I, to tell the truth. As you might have guessed I have always tried purposedly to "screw in" something unconventional, unidiomatic when phrasing different thoughts, ideas (not only in English, thus staggering my interlocutors). The principal point of mine is: "Leave out idiomacy, go into using language as a mason uses bricks". But grammaticality is everything, of course.